# Creating a pdf file using itext

Tags: itext

I need to create a .pdf file so it 'mimics' a Department of Treasury document.

I was wondering if it's best to use tables to display non db info, or should I simply add a paragraph at a time ?

My plan was to save non-configurable parts of the Treasury document in separate image files and load them into my .pdf at their correct location, but I was wondering if it's better to save these parts in their own .pdf files instead of image files ?

[image]

Comment: That's a very broad question, and you aren't even mentioning if you're using iText 5 or iText 7 (there's a huge difference).